# grails-2.3.7 plugins/repository not found

Tags: maven, grails, grails-plugin

Suddenly my Grails application having error by causing of some plugins are not found. I think the repository has been removed or move somewhere.

Code on my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
log "warn"
checksums true
legacyResolve false
.....
compile ":db-reverse-engineer:0.5"
compile ":cache:1.0.1"
compile ":jaxrs:0.10"
compile ":jasper:1.8.0"
.....
```

Having Error on my Grails Apps from today:

```
 Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:db-reverse-engineer:0.5
- org.grails.plugins:jaxrs:0.10
- org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.8.0


org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.ResolveException: Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:db-reverse-engineer:0.5
- org.grails.plugins:jaxrs:0.10
- org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.8.0
```

Note: grails repository has been removed from maven http://maven.restlet.org/org/

Can anyone suggest me to resolve those errors? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 17):

There is a temporary problem with the central repository in some versions of Grails. You can work around this in one of two ways:

1) Use Aether as your dependency resolver, in BuildConfig (recommended):

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
```

2) If you must use Ivy (not recommended) then add the following repo to your repositories in BuildConfig:

```
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/"
```

Comment: I faced the issue with grails 2.3.7 as of today. Solution 1) worked for me.(did not try 2 yet though as 1 worked).

Comment: This URL worked better for me on Grails 2.1.1:  mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"