# Grails not downloading plugins

Tags: grails, ivy

My grails 2.3.8 project is no longer downloading plugins. This has happened in the last few days.

I've set verbose output in BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails runApp
```

reports unresolved dependencies:

```
    module not found: org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0
==== grailsPlugins: tried
  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0!mail.zip:
  /Users/greg/Documents/development/git/liftyourgame-grails/webapp/lib/mail-1.0.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
  /Applications/Dev/grails-2.3.8/lib/org.grails.plugins/mail/ivy-1.0.xml
  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0!mail.zip:
  /Applications/Dev/grails-2.3.8/lib/org.grails.plugins/mail/jars/mail-1.0.zip
  /Applications/Dev/grails-2.3.8/lib/org.grails.plugins/mail/bundles/mail-1.0.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
  /Applications/Dev/grails-2.3.8/dist/mail-1.0.pom
  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0!mail.zip:
  /Applications/Dev/grails-2.3.8/dist/mail-1.0.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
  /Users/greg/.grails/2.3.8/cached-installed-plugins/mail-1.0.xml
  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0!mail.zip:
  /Users/greg/.grails/2.3.8/cached-installed-plugins/mail-1.0.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
  /Applications/Dev/grails-2.3.8/plugins/mail-1.0.pom
  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0!mail.zip:
  /Applications/Dev/grails-2.3.8/plugins/mail-1.0.zip
==== grailsCentral: tried
  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-mail/tags/RELEASE_1.0/mail-1.0.pom
  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0!mail.zip:
  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-mail/tags/RELEASE_1.0/grails-mail-1.0.zip
==== mavenCentral: tried
  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/mail/1.0/mail-1.0.pom
  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0!mail.zip:
  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/mail/1.0/mail-1.0.zip
```

If I download directly

```
http://grails.org/plugins/grails-mail/tags/RELEASE_1.0/grails-mail-1.0.zip
```

it downloads fine.

There is no proxy involved. I have also removed .grails and run the command again with the same result.

Comment: maybe it should be mail:1.0.5 ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but no improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impacting only older versions of Grails that use the Ivy resolver. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23594402/259167

Comment: Added to BuildConfig.groovy

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"

Answer (score -1):

This is a work around to your problem. If you can download the needed jar file manually, then download it and put it in the lib folder.