# resolve plugin dependency for grails 2.1.2 on Mac

Tags: grails, spring-security

For an older project running grails 2.1.2, I want to get the spring-security-core plugin RC-2 downloaded but it's not being resolved as yet.

Even if I create a new grails project on grails 2.1.2, I can't add this plugin either by defining build dependency or even by trying to install using command:

`grails install-plugin spring-security-core`

> Figured out that my local plugins-list-grailsCentral.xml isn't being examined when checking for plugin. Not sure, why?
>   From this xml, I downloaded the zip file then copied it in grails-install-dir/lib/org.grails.plugins/spring-security-core/jars (just because I saw that this path was being looked for by grails) and that dependency resolved.

I have now few other plugins not being resolved yet. How can I ask grails to look for this central grails plugin list? I already have following in BuildConfig.groovy.

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsCentral()
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()


    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
```

}

appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 1):

Phew;

Issue resolved by using another mavenRepo http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/

My BuildConfig.groovy repositories structure now looks like:

```
repositories {
    inherits true

    grailsCentral()
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    mavenRepo 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/'
}
```

Special thanks to 
[Why do I receive grails module not found and unresolved dependency warnings?](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204274970-Why-do-I-receive-grails-module-not-found-and-unresolved-dependency-warnings-)
and [grails-2.3.7 plugins/repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591347/grails-2-3-7-plugins-repository-not-found/23594402#23594402)